# Error installing poltergeist on ruby 2.0

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I am having problems installing the poltergeist gem. I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing poltergeist:
poltergeist requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

I am using ruby-2.0.0-p195 on a OS X Mountain Lion v10.8.4. My gem list is as follows:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.13)
activemodel (3.2.13)
activerecord (3.2.13)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.13)
addressable (2.3.4)
albacore (0.3.5)
arel (3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.10)
builder (3.2.2, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
capybara (2.1.0)
capybara-screenshot (0.3.13)
childprocess (0.3.9)
chromedriver-helper (0.0.5)
chronic (0.9.1)
cucumber (1.3.2)
data_magic (0.14)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
faker (1.1.2)
faye-websocket (0.4.7)
ffi (1.9.0)
gherkin (2.12.0)
headless (1.0.1)
hike (1.2.3)
http_parser.rb (0.5.3)
httpclient (2.3.3)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
jar_wrapper (0.1.7)
journey (1.0.4)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.23)
mini_portile (0.5.0)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.7.6)
nokogiri (1.6.0)
page-object (0.9.0)
page_navigation (0.9)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rake (10.0.4)
rspec (2.13.0)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
ruby (0.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
rvm (1.11.3.7)
selenium (0.2.10)
selenium-webdriver (2.33.0)
sprockets (2.2.2)
thread_safe (0.1.0)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.14)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
watir-webdriver (0.6.4)
websocket (1.0.7)
xpath (2.0.0)
yml_reader (0.2)
zip (2.0.2)
```

I am presuming the poltergeist gem should be compatible with ruby 2.0 as version 1.3.0 is quite recent. The page - http://rubygems.org/gems/poltergeist  lists the following gems as dependencies:

```
capybara ~> 2.1.0
faye-websocket < 0.5.0, >= 0.4.4
http_parser.rb ~> 0.5.3
```

As you can see from my gem list I have the gems installed but yet I get the error.

Anybody got any idea why I am getting the error?

Comment: I dont think poltergeist supports ruby-2.0 as of now see the doc https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/tree/v1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Got this sorted.

I ran the command rvm use 2.0, then gem install poltergeist and it installed successfully.